# need the CMS path directive for a app/code module folder

Tags: magento2, module, javascript, cms, folder

i added my own module under `/app/code/my/module/` , activated it and put a java script under `/app/code/my/module/view/frontend/web/js/myjs/myjs.js`

it works so far. The javascript is called within a cms page via `data-mage-init`.
The javascript istself needs some configuration arguments, as beside others a folder, to put some temporary data for the java script to work. : Argument is: `folder = "/myjs/temp"`

The problem is, that the js expects the folder now to be under

`root-folder/myjs/temp`  (ok, its clear somehow) , but it should be within my Module folder:

`root-folder/app/code/my/module/view/frontend/web/js/myjs/temp`

How can i fix the path within the argument in the cms page?